# Rails 3 - heroku PGError: ERROR: type modifier is not allowed for type "text"

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, typeerror

I am a newbie on Rails and doing ok so far. I wanted to find out what schema file is uploaded when you do heroku rake db:setup. Because even though I have deleted a table it keeps trying to create it on heroku and gives error.

I even tried recreating the table but it keeps remembering the old setting and errors out.

> PGError: ERROR:  type modifier is not allowed for type "text" LINE 1:
>   "trainings" ("id" serial primary key, "content" text(255),...

It's trying to create table trainings with content column text but I no longer have that setting and I think the setting is saved somewhere.

I even tried deleting my app and restarting it but no luck.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried rake db:drop to drop all the tables? then start again from rake db:migrate.

Comment: thanks for the lightening reply :) May be this is a sign of being newbie or just enough sleep before trying again. But I just removed the offending column, git push and pushed it to heroku and worked with no problems. But I am sure I tried that for about 4 hours yesterday with no success.

It works now. Lucky I didn't need that column. Ill try it with the column when there is time in hand.

Comment: ok curiosity got the better of me and dropped the tables but now when I do db:migrate it says "Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password doesn't match confirmation" on DeviseCreateAdminUsers when creating admin_users table. I have active admin installed. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, sorry to increase your pain :) I haven't used Devise before, but from the railscast, it seems like you need to run "rails generate devise 'your_user_model'" to create your user model before doing rake db:migrate. (http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)

Comment: Hmm... After reading the AsciiCast more carefully, the above method doesn't seem to be a remedy. It does not really make sense that db:migrate complaints about the validation when it is just creating tables... Are you trying to insert record into admin_users table in any of the migration files by any chance?

Comment: well I have switched the login for now, so no I am not trying to insert a user. But I did a db:reset and that fixed it (locally). And on the heroku db:migrate doesn't work only db:setup. Something tells me that is not healthy once I go live

Comment: switched off the login for the Active admin, i mean. It was conflicting with my current login setup with the users side.

Comment: Sorry for not being of help. I found out that heroku actually does not allow dropping/creating database (so, considering that you successfully finished the 'drop' part, I assume you did that only in the local environment). You have to use rake pg:reset instead in heroku environment. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake

Answer (score 8):

the default database on heroku is postgresql. And the text type in postgresql does not accept a size: it is unlimited.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  type modifier is not allowed for type "text"

When I tried to set `name` column with `TEXT(20)` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE p1 (
  id INT,
  name TEXT(20) -- Here
);
```

So, I removed `(20)` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
CREATE TABLE p1 (
  id INT,
  name TEXT -- Here
);
```

Or, I used `VARCHAR(20)` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
CREATE TABLE p1 (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20) -- Here
);
```